# Error in Ionic plugin AES256: Metadata version mismatch for module found version 4, expected 3

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I am using AES256 ionic plugin in my project. (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes256/)

When I try to run: `ionic cordova build android`, works, but when I run: `ionic cordova build android --prod`, throws the fallowing error :

```
$ ionic cordova build android --prod --release
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android
[16:00:06]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.12
[16:00:06]  build prod started ...
[16:00:06]  clean started ...
[16:00:06]  clean finished in 10 ms
[16:00:06]  copy started ...
[16:00:06]  ngc started ...
[16:00:12]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[16:00:12]  Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
            C:/workspace/app/node_modules/@ionic-native/aes-256/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/workspace/app/node_modules/@ionic-native/aes-256/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
    at C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23023:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at extractProgramSymbols (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
    at AotCompiler.compileAll (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:30:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:61:30)
    at Object.doCodegen (C:\workspace\app\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\codegen.js:6:51)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

My `ionic info`:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.5
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
   @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\tm\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

In config.xml I have: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption" spec="1.1.0" />`

In package.json I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/aes-256": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.0", ....
```

Comment: @ionic/app-scripts seem to be outdated. Update them and try

Comment: Try to downgrade `cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption` to `1.0.3`

Comment: I updated `@ionic/app-scripts` to latest version (**3.2.1**)  and I downgrade `cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption` to **1.0.3** but still not work. Same error with build **--prod**. 
Error seems to be thrown at  `ngc started ...`. 
**ngc** just execute in build --prod

Comment: I solved my problem updating all `@ionic-native/` dependencies to latest version (^4.18.0) and updanting all `@angular/` dependencies to ^5.2.11, like:

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
   ...
    "@ionic-native/aes-256": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.18.0",
   ...`   **see [https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15324](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15324)**